# how to add linq result to list with key

Tags: c#

I have a linq which is inside a for loop,im adding the results to a list using addRange() but it will add whole thing in a single set,for example my first loop result has 16 items,the second has 10 items,...i want them to be added to list like this then i can see in list how many and which  items has been added on each query

```
public List<statisticsDaily> dailyStat(List<string> id,string dtFrom,string dtTo)
            {
                List<StatisticsDaily> rsltofquery = new List<StatisticsDaily>();
                for (int i = 0; i < id.Count; i++)
                {
                    var rslt = (from d in db.statDaily
                                join s in db.masterData on d.m_turbine_id equals s.m_turbine_id
                                where d.m_turbine_id == IPAddress.Parse(id[i]) && d.m_date >= frm && d.m_date <= to
                                select new StatisticsDaily
                                {
                                    m_wind_speed = d.m_wind_speed,
                                    Date = d.m_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                    name = s.turbine_name,
                                    Production = d.m_energy_prod,
                                    Availability = d.m_corrected_av


                                }
                         ).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(s => s.Date).ToList();
                                    rsltofquery.AddRange(rslt);

                }
```

Comment: You have your method `dailyStat()` defined that way, that it returns a list of `statisticsDaily` objects. That is what you are currently getting, one big list with all the `statisticsDaily` objects you have read. What should the return type of that method be instead? How do you want to use the return value, how should it be build? How do you want to use the return value at the place where you call the `dailyStat()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have collection of collections like `List<List<StatisticsDaily>>`.

So yours code will be:

```
public List<List<statisticsDaily>> dailyStat(List<string> id,string dtFrom,string dtTo)
{
  List<List<StatisticsDaily>> rsltofquery = new List<List<StatisticsDaily>>();
  for (int i = 0; i < id.Count; i++)
  {
    var rslt = (from d in db.statDaily
    join s in db.masterData on d.m_turbine_id equals s.m_turbine_id
      where d.m_turbine_id == IPAddress.Parse(id[i]) && d.m_date >= frm && d.m_date <= to
      select new StatisticsDaily 
      {
        m_wind_speed = d.m_wind_speed,
        Date = d.m_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        name = s.turbine_name,
        Production = d.m_energy_prod,
        Availability = d.m_corrected_av
      }).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(s => s.Date).ToList();
    rsltofquery.Add(rslt);
  }
}
```

If you want to use all elements, not in parts, you can use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1):

```
var x = dailyStat(id, dtFrom, dtTo);
foreach (var e in x.SelectMany(d => d)) ...
```